# Redirect POST - Domain to IP

Tags: php, html, redirect, traffic

I just bought a domain name (for example test.com) on namecheap and since I don't bought a host there I redirect the traffic to my raspberry apache2 webserver which has a static IP.

All of that works great but If I want to send a post request to the domain for example test.com/login.php it has to redirect to ip/login.php. But the post request doesn't arrives.

How do I redirect the traffic from that domain to the raspberry?

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? Why don't you just set a A record pointing to your IP?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set my A record and used an url redirect record instead which didn't work.